# Adding <Icon> from react-native-elements to bottomTabNavigator shows error

Tags: react-native, icons, react-navigation, react-native-elements

I'm trying to add icons to my bottomTabNavigator using Icons from `react-native-elements`.

```
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from "react-navigation"
import { ServicesNavigator } from "./services-navigator"
import { AccountScreen } from "../screens/account-screen/account-screen"
import { Icon } from "react-native-elements"

export const BottomTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  services: {
    screen: ServicesNavigator,
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarLabel:"Services",
      tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
        <Icon name="ios-build" type="Ionicon" size={10} />
      )
    },
  },
  account: { screen: AccountScreen },
})
```

The code above shows the following error in ios: `Unexpected token, expected "</>/<=/>="` around the line where `<Icon>` is.
I've tried looking online but I can't seem to fix my problem. Any help would be appreicated!

Comment: type="ionicon" might help

Comment: Nope, still getting the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the problem. All this time my file's extension was `.ts`, which does not support jsx, instead of `.tsx`. Changing the file extension to `.tsx` did it for me.

Answer (score 0):

those settings should not be within the RouteConfigs. Studying https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/tab-based-navigation.html#customizing-the-appearance you should do more like

```
export const BottomTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
    services: ServicesNavigator,
    account: AccountScreen,
  },
  {
    defaultNavigationOptions: () => {
      tabBarIcon: () => <Icon name="ios-build" type="Ionicon" size={10} />
    },
  },
})
```

Comment: Nope, still not working. Even using the exact format from the react navigation website is giving me an error. `Type 'RegExp' is missing the following properties from type 'Icon': context, setState, forceUpdate, render, and 3 more.` It seems like the return value should be a react component or something?

Comment: I finally found the problem. All this time my file's extension was .ts, which does not support jsx, instead of .tsx. Changing the file extension to .tsx did it for me.